# Checkbox for Android

Tags: android, android-checkbox

I am trying to use a checkbox with the below layout configuration.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
            android:id="@+id/gdprOptIn"
            fontPath="fonts/AvenirNextRegular.ttf"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/medium_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/medium_margin"
            android:button="@drawable/checkbox"
            android:checked="false"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/default_margin"
            android:text="@string/opt_in_gdpr"
            android:textColor="@color/paper_ink_light"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:gravity="top"/>
```

I can't find a way to:
   - Avoid the text to be clickable. I can check/uncheck the box by taping on the text
   - Add round/square outline around the checkbox to make it more visible for the use.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the text to be clickable, you can replace a single `<CheckBox>` tag with a `<LinearLayout>` holding a `<CheckBox>` and a `<TextView>`. For example, this:

```
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="hello world"/>
```

can be replaced by this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="hello world"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

If you want to draw a box around the checkbox to make it stand out even more, you could wrap it in a `<FrameLayout>` with a colored background:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fac">

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </FrameLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="hello world"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, the only things is that my text is the text in the Text view contains a clickable element, let's world is clickable. I have used a SpannableStringBuilder to make it but it seems that it become not clickable or the click event is catched by the LinearLayout. I have set the LL to clickable:false but still not work